# How to set global mime type by extension?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, mime-types, content-type

Is there a way to specify what mime type all files with an extension should be for the entire bucket?

This is very easy when hosting files on Apache and it causes problems when a browser expects our subtitles to be `text/vtt`. I upload files to the bucket once every few months, and I'll use anything from Rubber Ducky, the web gui, gcs fuse or gsutil on a number of computers. It seems like an insane hassle to write an app just to upload files with the correct mime type.

There is a way to set the global default ACL, surely there must be a way to set the global default VTT mime.

**Update**

Setting use_magicfile=True in the GSUtil section of your boto config file makes mime detection more accurate, alleviating the issue a bit   https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/183#issuecomment-35741417

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no way to configure an extension-based MIME type on a bucket in GCS. You would need to change the code that uploads the files to set the MIME type at the time of uploading.

If you just want to fix the MIME type on a bunch of objects based on extension you could do that using a gsutil command like:

```
 gsutil -m setmeta -h "Content-Type:text/vtt" gs://your-bucket/**.txt
```

Comment: I'll just cron this once a day or something... THANK YOU